# Scala: create a map based UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Schema of dataframe df10

```
root
|-- ID: string (nullable = true)
|-- KEY: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Code

```
val gid1 = 505
val array1: Array[String] = Array("atm_P3", "fee_P6", "c_P8", "card_P4", "iss_P5", "vat_P7")
//simplistic udf
val isSubsetArrayUDF = udf { a : Seq[String] =>  if (!{for (elem <- a) yield array1.contains(elem)}.contains(false) == true) gid1 else 0}
val df11 = df10.withColumn("is_subset_KEY", isSubsetArrayUDF(col("tran_particular")))
```

I need to assign each 'KEY' in df10 a 'GID' using the given map

```
Map(KEY -> WrappedArray(atm_P3, fee_P6, c_P8, card_P4, iss_P5, vat_P7, cif_P1, cif_P2), GID -> 505)
Map(KEY -> WrappedArray(atm_P3, fee_P6, c_P8, card_P4, iss_P5, vat_P7, cif_P2), GID -> 423)
...
```

How to achieve so using a udf?

Comment: Where did `GID -> 423` come from? Please create a [mcve].

Comment: The map is created using command ***val KeyGidMap = grammer3.select("GID", "KEY").collect.map(r=> Map(grammer3.columns.zip(r.toSeq):_*))*** on a datafame

Comment: you will have to provide us with complete information which can be understood